# BIRT Chart Axes issue

Tags: charts, report, reporting, birt

I have a BIRT report design which has linear chart in it. I want to start X axis and Y axis values from Maximum Number at origin e.g. from 0 to -100. So I went to Edit Chart->Format Chart->X axis->Origin and set it to Max and same for Y axis. But the problem is X-axis is displaying at the top rather than at the bottom side and Y-axis is displaying at right side rather than on left side.

I know is going there because it is third quadrant of the chart but I want to bring it to first quadrant.

How can I bring both the axes in the left and bottom sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the above query by using the following link

[BIRT Reversing Chart Scale](http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2008/12/birt-reversing-chart-scale.html)

We need to make changes in the script according to our requirement such as type of the chart, name of the series and the scale. The link shows example of scale from 0 to 100. I want to use it for negative values i.e. Max=0 and Min=-100. So I made the changes in the global variable to support it for negative values.